# (C#) System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: "Плохие данные. "

Tags: c#, ssl, кодировка, tls, decrypt

Здравствуйте. 
Я пишу свой TLS сервер, но возникла такая проблема, я пытаюсь расшифровать сообщение Finished (Encrypted Handshake Message) приватным ключём сертификата, но выдается исключение :

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: "Плохие данные."
```

Код:

```
internal static X509Certificate2 ServerCert = new X509Certificate2("SRVCert.pfx","******");
internal static X509Certificate2 CA_Cert = new X509Certificate2("CA.crt");
internal static RSA PublicKey = (RSA)ServerCert.PublicKey.Key;
internal static RSA PrivateKey = (RSA)ServerCert.PrivateKey;
```

ServerCert  содержит также приватный ключ. Сертификат и сертификат CA отправляется клиенту.

Ниже сообщение Finished (HEX):

```
16030100301c7dd49c1290dd83774e38465a81e7d98fdf5b962881323b4348bb0e312dd9c5260656fe230afe8e69f61c712f5567e2
```

Пожалуйста подскажите, что я делаю не так

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сообщение Finished шифруется блочным шифром с динамически вычисляемым ключом. Сертификаты не принимают участия на этом этапе.

Процедура вычисления динамических ключей для TLS 1.2 описана в `RFC 5246` глава `6.3`:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.3

Comment: Благодарю. Подскажите пожалуйста, как вычислить MasterSecret. Все данные для его вычисления имеются (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774271/tls-%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-master-secret-%d0%b2-c)