# (TLS) Вычисление Master Secret в C#

Tags: c#, ssl, tls

Здравствуйте. Не могу найти информацию, как получить Master Secret из компонентов: Client Random, Server Random, PreMasterSecret . Это всё есть в byte[]. Пожалуйста, подскажите как вычислить MasterSecret в C#. Желательно с кодами на C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это зависит от выбранного набора шифров (cipher suite), и от того, включено ли расширение Extended Master Secret. Лучше посмотрите исходники, как все работает. Для C# есть реализация TLS от BouncyCastle.

В меня есть своя учебная реализация TLS, конкретный метод вычисления Master Secret здесь:
https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul/Network/Tls/CipherSuiteBuilder.cs#L67

```
// включено ли расширение
if (SecurityParameters.ExtendedMasterSecret)
{
    // Hash может быть SHA256 или SHA384 в зависимости от Cipher Suite
    // HandshakeData - все переданные байты в сообщениях
    var sessionHash = Hash(SecurityParameters.HandshakeData.ToArray());
    // PseudoRandomFunction - стандартная функция для TLS 1.2 описана в RFC 5246
    SecurityParameters.MasterSecret = PseudoRandomFunction(
        KeyExchange.PreMasterSecret,
        "extended master secret",
        sessionHash,
        48);
}
else
{
    SecurityParameters.MasterSecret = PseudoRandomFunction(
        KeyExchange.PreMasterSecret,
        "master secret",
        ByteArray.Concat(SecurityParameters.ClientRandom, SecurityParameters.ServerRandom),
        48);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Zergatul,можно Вас попросить, чтобы Вы сделали мне класс, у меня что-то не получилось =(. Мне нужно только извлечь mastersecret. Я использую CipherSuite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035), для меня это очень важно. Спасибо!